# How to move sub-branch to other parent branch?

Tags: git, github, sourcetree

I am working on a project using [githup](/questions/tagged/githup) and [sourcetree](/questions/tagged/sourcetree).
The situation is that I should take a branch from develop branch but I forgot that and I took it from the master branch and did some commits.
Is there is a way to move this sub-branch from master to develop with this commits?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 git rebase --onto develop origin/master yourbranch
```

origin/master should be the start of the branch to move